# How do I activate my conda environment for VS Code python debugger and testing?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

When I try to run the debugger:

```
C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara> cmd /C "C:/Users/Philip/miniconda3/envs/capra/python.exe c:\Users\Philip\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.101144\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher 53607 -- c:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\updater.py "
C:\Users\Philip\miniconda3\envs\capra\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
```

I've worked out that if I install `numpy` into my `base` environment then I can get around the error. The question is how to activate the `capra` environment for the debugger?

I've tried following the [guidance](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_choose-a-debugging-environment) from VS Code:

```
1. pythonPath property of the selected debug configuration in launch.json
```

My `launch.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "C:/Users/Philip/miniconda3/envs/capra/python.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Next:

```
2. python.pythonPath setting in the workspace settings.json
```

I restart `VS Code` and get:

```
We removed the "python.pythonPath" setting from your settings.json file as the setting is no longer used by the Python extension. You can get the path of your selected interpreter in the Python output channel. [Learn more](https://aka.ms/AA7jfor).
```

Lastly:

```
3. python.pythonPath setting in the user settings.json
```

My user settings file:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/WINDOWS/System32/cmd.exe",
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "python.venvPath": "C:/Users/Philip/miniconda3/envs/capra",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/Philip/miniconda3/envs/capra/python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:/WINDOWS/System32/cmd.exe",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    
    ]
}
```

Still get the same numpy error.

Worth mentioning that I get exactly the same error when I look at the `Python Test Log` output after trying to discover tests.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'conda activate capra' in terminal? When we create and select a coda environment, VSCode will first enter the base environment, and after using this sentence to activate it, it will enter the newly created 'capra' environment. (You could also use"  'ctrl+shift+`  " to open a new terminal, it will automatically activate.') Reference: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Comment: Yep. Running the debugger seems to reset this. See first code block for the message I get. It looks like the terminal isn't in any environment. However, as I mention if I install numpy in my base environment then the error goes away...

Answer (score 5):

You click on the `Python 3.6 .....` bottom right side as shown in the picture below [image: Click on red square part Python 3.6. ....]

Then you just have to select the environments you have already created as shown in the picture below
[image: Select the environment in red circle]

Then you run the code and code will run in the selected environment.

Comment: I have selected the ```capra``` environment. Using the debugger seems to kick me out of it and into ```base```

Comment: Debugger will kick you into base only when using VS Code terminal and with command `conda activate capra`  ..... Use the above method I mentioned it will never kick you out of environment. I have confirmed it and I had same problem but after so many searches the above method I have shown is working fine

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you could try the following steps to use conda environment:
(Example: Use python3.8 to create a conda environment named 'capra'.)

1. Create a conda environment.

> `conda create -n capra python=3.8`

After the creation is complete, reload VSCode, refresh and load several times.

2. Select conda environment.

   click the lower left corner of VSCode to select the environment just created.
   [image]
3. Activate the conda environment. You could use shortcut keys directly: Ctrl+Shift+`

   [image]

When debugging the code, the terminal shows that it is in the created environment:

[image]

4. Install the required modules in the current conda environment.

In addition, for the'`removed "python.pythonPath" setting`' you mentioned, the reason is that you set the'`workspace settings.json`'. Now the python extension does not use the'pythonPath' here. When we set both in the two setting files, it will be removed. This will not affect the use of conda environment.

Comment: Why do I need to create a new environment? As per the question I'm looking to ensure that the debugger runs using the ```capra``` environment?

Comment: @Jossy Yes, you can use the capra environment you created and then activate it. You could refer to it from the second step. The complete steps are provided for your reference.

Comment: @Jossy To better explain this process, I edited the above content.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Visual Studio Code version:1.70.2, the Python environment selection was on the bottom right. I clicked there and changed the environment to the conda location. To find your conda environment and respective python version, issue the commands: pip --version and python --version.
[Where to click in VisualStudioCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ilR.png)